# bootstrap 4 grid system doesnt float automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I am developing a site using bootstrap 4 , everything works fine but the column that i have, need to be floated automatically , but it doesn't , is there any issue with bootstrap 4 or am i missing anything , 
As this can be solve too writing custom css but i do think i am missing something , please help .

```
<?php
include ("layouts/header.php");
?>
<section class="booking">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-header">
                    <h2>Booking Procedures</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="section-content">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form>
                        <div class="card text-center">
                          <div class="card-header">
                            Booking Step 2 Of 2
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-block">
                            <p>All * fields are compulsory</p>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option>Title</option>
                                        <option>Mr.</option>
                                        <option>Mrs.</option>
                                        <option>Miss</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" required="required">
                                        <option>Nationality</option>
                                        <option>Chinese</option>
                                        <option>Indian</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Birth *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Occupation" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Detail Mailing Address *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Landline" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Passport Number *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Place Of Issue *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Issue *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Date Of Expiry *" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" required="required">
                                        <option>How did you find us</option>
                                        <option>Friends</option>
                                        <option>Family</option>
                                        <option>Online</option>
                                        <option>Travel Blog</option>
                                        <option>Trip Advisor</option>
                                        <option>Others</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Emergency Contact * "></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-12">
                            <p>Note: Please kindly note that you should be covered for, I- medical expenses, II- emergency air ambulance &amp; III- Trip cancellation to plan this trip.</p>
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sample3">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php include("layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

Result i want 
[image]

Result i got 
[image: result]

Comment: You know BS4 **doesn't use floats**...right?

Comment: is it ? i need to read the documentation properly ... my bad

Comment: BS4 is based on Flexbox.

Comment: how will i be able to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not well formatted, you are using **col-** inside **col-** without the use of **row**. You need to have something like that

```
<div class="container" >
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and to have nested row use this :

```
<div class="container" >
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

refer to the documentation :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

Comment: maybe you could share with us the result you want ? so we see the issue clearly